# regexp not working in JS, but working in regex101

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the next regexp

```
content = content.replace(/(\bTABLE\s{1}FILE\b)/g,'<span style="color:#996600">$1</span>');
```

The sample text is: "table file TABLE FILE ASD" without quotes.

When I test it in chrome, it does nothing, but if I go to https://regex101.com/#javascript and run the regexp, it just works :S

Someone can tell me what I'm missing? Its weird...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: doing `"table file TABLE FILE ASD".replace(/(\bTABLE\s{1}FILE\b)/g,'<span style="color:#996600">$1</span>');` works fine for me in chrome. are you sure your `content` variable is what you expect?

Comment: Works fine In Chrome: `content = "table file TABLE FILE ASD"; 
content.replace(/(\bTABLE\s{1}FILE\b)/g,'<span style="color:#996600">$1</span>');` => `"table file <span style="color:#996600">TABLE FILE</span> ASD"`

Comment: I trie both anwers and they're working... something is wrong with the recovered text in the content var, if I do alert(content) I have the text I put before, but maybe there's some non visible characters. Thanks :)